# How to split a git branch into two branches?

Tags: git, split, branch

I'm trying to help out a coworker who accidentally created one feature branch from another feature branch, rather than creating the second one from master. Here is essentially what we have now…

```
Master ---A---B---C
                   \
              Foo   E---F---F---H
                                 \
                            Bar   J---K---L---M
```

And here is what we'd like to have…

```
Master ---A---B---C
                  |\
             Foo  | E---F---F---H
                  |
             Bar  J---K---L---M
```

One way I thought of would be to create FooV2 and BarV2 branches, and cherry-pick the individual commits into the appropriate V2 branches. But I'm curious, is there a better way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks to me like you could:

```
git checkout J
git rebase master
```

Edit:

I tried what I suggested and it doesn't work.  knittl's suggestion doesn't work (on my box).  Here's what did work for me:

```
git rebase --onto master foo bar
```

Comment: Thanks a lot; the edited version worked great!

In case anyone needs some more details around this, there is a "More Interesting Rebases" section of Pro Git book that covers almost this exact example: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Comment: `git rebase --onto master foo bar` means: Take "bar" without "foo" and place it onto master

Comment: @schoetbi: Your comment is the VIP in this whole thread. Before seeing it, I did not understand any of the answers.

Answer (score 148):

For a more general answer that will help us understand things a bit better than just "run this command", we need a larger example. So, let's pretend you're actually in this situation:

```
---A---B---C <= Master
            \
             E---F---F---H <= Foo
                          \
                           J---K---L---M <= Bar
                                        \
                                         N---O---P---Q <= Baz
```

And here is what we'd like to have…

```
---A---B---C <= Master
           |\
           | E---F---F---H <= Foo
           |\
           | J---K---L---M <= Bar
            \
             N---O---P---Q <= Baz
```

Thankfully, Git has a solution for us in the options to the `rebase` command!

```
git rebase --onto [newParent] [oldParent] [branchToMove]
```

What this means can be broken down into parts:

1. `rebase` - Change the parents of *something*
2. `--onto` - This is the flag that tells git to use this alternate rebase syntax
3. `newParent` - This is the branch that the branch you are rebasing will have as it's parent
4. `oldParent` - This is the branch that the branch you are rebasing currently has as it's parent
5. `branchToMove` - This is the branch that you are moving (rebasing)

The bit about "old parent branch" can be a little confusing, but what it's really doing is it's saying "ignore the changes from my old parent when doing the rebase". The `oldParent` is how you define where the branch you are moving (ie. `branchToMove`) *starts*.

So, what are the commands to execute in our situation?

```
git rebase --onto Master Bar Baz
git rebase --onto Master Foo Bar
```

Note that the order of these commands matter because we need to pull each branch off of the *end* of the "branch chain".

Comment: Takes all the magic out of it, in the best sense possible. Just used this to un-fubar(baz) a feature branch where I had done some work on Foo, then some commits towards Bar, then some more Foo, but all on the same commit line. #fail

Comment: @BenMosher: I realize this was a long time ago, but did you actually succeed or fail in using this approach to turn a foo-bar-foo into a clean foo and bar?

Comment: @Superole: IIRC, I did. have used `--onto` several times hence as well. 

Answer (score 7):

You can rebase your Bar branch onto master:

```
git rebase --onto C H M
```

If some patches conflict, you have to resolve them manually (but you also have to do that when cherry picking). Word of caution: don't rebase when the history has been published already.