# how to divide one pull request into two different pull request on github

Tags: git, github

How can I divide one pull request into two pull requests?
I committed ten times in one pull request, and I want to divide them into two different pull requests because the first six commits are unrelated to the last four commits.
I use Ubuntu os with git.
As I am new to git, I am wondering how to input git commands step by step to do that.
Any advice would be be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

You basically have a duplicate of [Splitting a Branch in 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355904/split-a-git-branch-into-two-branches)  The graphs there are good so not bothering to duplicate them.

First create a second branch pointing at your sixth commit

```
git branch branch2 HEAD~4
```

or

```
git branch branch2 COMMIT_6_SHA
```

branch2 is now done and ready to create a pull request for the first 6 commits.

Now you want to use `git rebase --onto` to move your existing branch with the other 4 commits so they are hanging off your upstream

```
git rebase --onto @{u} branch2
```

And that's it.