# Break linear git commits into two merged branches

Tags: git

I have a long linear git history. I want to rebase some commits so it is as if I created a feature branch and merged it back to master using `git merge --no-ff master`.

Current

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
                         master
```

Desired

```
                   master
A -> B   ->   E -> F
      \      /
       C -> D
            feature
```

I thought to do something like

```
git checkout D
git checkout -b feature
git rebase B
git merge --no-ff E
```

But `D` already has `B` in its history, so this doesn't do anything. I know how to rebase `E` off of `B` ([Split a git branch into two branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355904/split-a-git-branch-into-two-branches)), but here, the desired version of `E` has two parents.

Some additional details is that originally my project was structured like `Desired`, and `E` is really a merge commit. I somehow then linearized my history using `git rebase` to remove some unwanted files from old commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by resetting master to `B` to be able to create the merge commit `E`:

```
git checkout D
git checkout -b feature
git checkout master

                         master
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
               feature
```

```
git reset --hard B

     master
A -> B 
      \      
       C -> D
            feature
```

```
git merge --no-ff feature

              master
A -> B   ->   E
      \      /
       C -> D
            feature
```

```
git cherry-pick F

                   master
A -> B   ->   E -> F
      \      /
       C -> D
            feature
```

Maybe not the shortest solution but it does things in the right order so it makes it easier to understand.

**Note:** Don't forget to save somewhere the hash of `F` as `git reset --hard B` will make it become a dangling commit.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout -b feature D
git checkout -b master F
git rebase -i B  # change pick C, pick D to drop C, drop D
git merge D
```